# Java Call Interception Logging

Tags: java, trace

I would like a program that logs every call I made to a class folder like com.mycompany.mylibrary and outputs a valid java program, much like http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace does in Linux.

Do you guys know any call interceptor like the one I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use some aspect-oriented mechanism like [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). Although I'm confused by what you mean by 'outputs a valid Java program'

Answer (score 0):

I have found:
http://www.jroller.com/carlossg/entry/tracing_an_application_using_aspectj
but I will have to recompile the jars I need to trace since AspectJ poincuts are injected at compile time. So I am still looking for a solution that does not need any recompilation just like ltrace works for C.